# How to update a file using PyGithub?

Tags: python, pygithub

I want to know which method should I call (and on which object) and how to call that method (required parameters and their meanings).

Comment: Two places to start: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/ and https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/InputFileContent.py

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import github

g = github.Github(token)
# or  g = github.Github(login, password)

repo = g.get_user().get_repo("repo_name")
file = repo.get_file_contents("/your_file.txt")

# update
repo.update_file("/your_file.txt", "your_commit_message", "your_new_file_content", file.sha)
```

> If you are using  token then you should have at least ***repo*** scope
>   of your token to do it. 
>   https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes

**See:** https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/ and https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub

Answer (score 6):

As of 2021, the PyGithub API has changed and there's an example of how to do this: https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Repository.html#update-a-file-in-the-repository

```py
repo = g.get_repo("PyGithub/PyGithub")
contents = repo.get_contents("test.txt", ref="test")
repo.update_file(contents.path, "more tests", "more tests", contents.sha, branch="test")
# {'commit': Commit(sha="b06e05400afd6baee13fff74e38553d135dca7dc"), 'content': ContentFile(path="test.txt")}
```

For `.update_file`, the first string is the message, the second string is the new contents of the file. Here's the [API description](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html?highlight=update_file#github.Repository.Repository.update_file):

```
update_file(path, message, content, sha, branch=NotSet, committer=NotSet, author=NotSet)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that the only practical difference seems to be `get_file_contents` → `get_contents`.